# Having a problem with IF function argument in Spreadsheet

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm trying to make this description generator, and I can't seem to make the first part work for one of the IF arguments as it does with the rest. It only checks the logical expression but doesn't bring the rest of the text body in the cell joined with & as it does in the case of the other IF arguments I have there linked one after the other. This [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vw6mnKIDZTRM0OjxVpHChUUtyHdURFyJ4tqEkHOwiRs/edit#gid=0) should make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first If statement encloses all the rest of the formula so if the regex matches "ck" the condition is satisfied, you get "click >" but nothing else happens. I think you can just move the final bracket so it is just after "select " like this:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(B4, "ck"),"click >",IF(REGEXMATCH(B4, "scd"),"scroll down > ",IF(REGEXMATCH(B4, "!"),"","select "))) & ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, IF(REGEXMATCH(""&
 SPLIT(B4, CHAR(10)), "^>.*"), 
 SPLIT(B4, CHAR(10)), TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(TRANSPOSE((SEQUENCE(1, COLUMNS(
 SPLIT(B4, CHAR(10))))<=SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(
 SPLIT(B4, CHAR(10))), 1, 0))*NOT(REGEXMATCH(
 SPLIT(B4, CHAR(10)), "^>.+")))), TRANSPOSE(SIGN(NOT(REGEXMATCH(
 SPLIT(B4, CHAR(10)), "^>.+"))))))&". "&
 SPLIT(B4, CHAR(10)))), "^0. ", ),"scd",""),"ck",""),"!",""))
```

[image]

Comment: that works nice, but it's interesting that it works like that. If the condition is not met it goes on with the & but if it is it doesn't

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(IFERROR(
 SPLIT(B1:B, CHAR(10)))="",,REGEXREPLACE({"", SEQUENCE(1, 100)}&". "&IFNA(VLOOKUP(
 TRIM(SPLIT(B1:B, CHAR(10))), 
 {"ck",  "click >";
  "box", "select box"; 
  "scd", "scroll down >"}, 2, 0), 
 SPLIT(B1:B, CHAR(10))), " ", CHAR(13)))),,9^9))), 
 " ", CHAR(10)), CHAR(13), " "), "^\. !?", ))
```

[image]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I488V1VFL-bC6ZsjiyF6Z3-IZAVHyPUqtUTB0yHQjps/edit#gid=0)